# I want to create a simple video player same like azure media service

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

I have azure media service already in my project and i am using C# core api and angular for frontend . now I want to replace ams with azure video indexer . I can use my old video from container using c# ?

Want to create a simple player from my azure container video file

Comment: Akash, based on my understanding of your question description, your are look to use Azure Video Indexer (AVI) to analyze and index your video files stored in Azure Blob Storage containers. If yes, you may use the AVI API to extract insights from your videos, such as keywords, topics, and transcripts. You can then use the Embed visual widgets in your application feature to embed the player in your application

Kindly provide more details about your requirement. 

You can use the API to upload your files, get detailed video insights, get URLs of embeddable insight and player widgets+

Comment: Adding more: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-video-indexer/upload-index-videos 



[Official Azure Media Services | Video Indexer Samples[(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-video-indexer)

Answer (score 0):

Akash, based on my understanding of your question description, your are look to use Azure Video Indexer (AVI) to analyze and index your video files stored in Azure Blob Storage containers. If yes, you may use the AVI API to extract insights from your videos, such as keywords, topics, and transcripts. You can then use the Embed visual widgets in your application feature to embed the player in your application Kindly provide more details about your requirement. You can use the API to upload your files, get detailed video insights, get URLs of embeddable insight and player widgets+

Adding more info:
[Official Azure Media Services | Video Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/upload-index-videos)

Samples:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-video-indexer

(summarizing from my comments above)

Comment: I want to create public url like this 
<iframe width="580" height="780" src="https://www.videoindexer.ai/embed/insights/f7849136-32c9-4913-8006-c19afe9f7674/10b0ddc720/?&locale=en&location=eastus" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>